# SyntaxError: invalid syntax без видимой причины в Python3.98

Tags: python-3.x

```
    from socket import *
serverPort = 8000 
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR
       serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort)) 
  print("Attacker box listening and awaiting instructions") 
connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept() 
print("Thanks for connecting to me "
           +str(addr)) 
message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
print(message) 
command ="" 
while command != "exit":
     command = input("Please enter a command: ") 
      connectionSocket.send(command.encode())
       message = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode() 
        print(message)
        
connectionSocket.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR)
connectionSocket.close()
```

> выдает ошибку

```
    File "/home/kali/Desktop/shell/shellServer.py", line 5
    serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort)) 
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Следите за запятыми.

Comment: и за закрывающими скобками

Answer (score 0):

Вы не закрыли скобку:
`serverSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR`

Должно быть:

```
serverPort = 8000 
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR) #<- скобка
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort)) 
print("Attacker box listening and awaiting instructions")
```